# JavaScript: how do I loop through these items outside of their function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is the input:

```
[ 'markdown',
  [ 'para', '“a paragraph”' ],
  [ 'hr' ],
  [ 'para', '\'another paragraph\'' ],
  [ 'para', 'test--test' ],
  [ 'para', 'test---test' ],
  [ 'bulletlist',
    [ 'listitem', '“a list item”' ],
    [ 'listitem', '“another list item”' ] ] ]
```

I'm using this function to find (recursively) each string in those arrays:

```
function findRecur(tree) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i]))
      findRecur(tree[i])
    else
      console.log(tree[i])
  }
}

function anotherFunc(tree, callback) {
  findRecur(tree)

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

output:

```
"a paragraph"
'another paragraph'
test--test
test---test
"a list item"
"another list item"
```

I wanted to do the `console.log` outside `anotherFunc` instead. So I did this:

```
function findRecur(tree) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i]))
      findRecur(tree[i])
    else
      return tree[i]
  }
}

function anotherFunc(tree, callback) {
  findRecur(tree, function(node) {
     console.log(node)
  })

  callback(null, tree) 
}
```

But nothing is being output. I think I have to add a second parameter to `findRecur` but not very sure how and what.

Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a callback parameter to your `findRecur` function. It makes no sense to pass two parameters into a function that only looks at the first one.

```
function findRecur(tree, callback) {
    for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(tree[i])) {
            findRecur(tree[i], callback);
        } else {
            callback(tree[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call your function like this:

```
findRecur(data, function(text) { console.log(text); });
```

Or just like this:

```
findRecur(data, console.log);
```

Comment: i think you are missing callback as parameter in recursive call. should be `findRecur(tree[i], callback)`

Comment: @atornblad Oh, thanks. I'm still having problems understanding `callbacks` in JavaScript. What does the code do when enclosing `tree[i]` with `callback()`?

Comment: The line `callback(tree[i]);` takes the function passed into the currently running function (`findRecur`) and calls it, just as you would call any function. Remember, you are passing a function as the value of the `callback` parameter, so calling `callback()` calls the function that you passed in. `tree[i]` is simply the only parameter of the function refered to in `callback`.

Answer (score 0):

findRecur needs the function that will be called and it should call it in the else

so for example

```
function findRecur(tree, fn) {
  for (var i = 1; i < tree.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(tree[i]))
      findRecur(tree[i])
    else
      fn(tree[i])
  }
}
```